# Matriz en python distinto a matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Al crear la siguiente matriz en matlab me queda de un tamaño (1x315)
Pero al crearla en python me queda de (315,)
Por lo que al a hora de graficar me dice: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (315,) and (1, 315)

El código en matlab:

```
theta=-pi/2:.01:pi/2;
```

En python:

```
theta=np.arange(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2,0.01)
```

Como puedo hacer ese mismo rango en python y que la variable theta me quede (1x315)
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer lo que quieres hacer se puede llevar a cabo con la funcion `reshape` [(ver)](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
theta = np.arange(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 0.01).reshape(1, 315)

print(theta.shape)
## (1, 315)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me fue muy útil tu ayuda